# Почему происходит зацикливание

Tags: javascript, html

Только начал изучать js и что-то совсем не могу понять почему происходит зацикливание в **12** строке кода `(while...)`, будьте так добры, объясните причину

```js
var numberOfTrees = prompt("Number of trees");
while (typeof(numberOfTrees) != Number) {
  try {
    numberOfTrees = Number(numberOfTrees);
    if (numberOfTrees == 1) {
      document.write("One tree");
    } else {
      document.write("p".repeat(numberOfTrees));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результатом выполнения [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) является строка, поэтому и сравнивать надо со строкой:

```
while (typeof(numberOfTrees) != 'number'){
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyVeryFirstEx</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var numberOfTrees = prompt("Number of trees");

    while (typeof(numberOfTrees) != 'number') {
      console.log(numberOfTrees, typeof(numberOfTrees));
      numberOfTrees = Number(numberOfTrees);
      console.log(numberOfTrees, typeof(numberOfTrees));

      if (numberOfTrees == 1) {
        document.write("One tree");
      } else {
        document.write("p".repeat(numberOfTrees));
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Это конечно прекрасно, но убрав try потерялась возможность вывести сообщение о том, что задан неверный тип данных (не number, а что-то иное)

Comment: @Chaddydaddy В коде, который Вы привели, нет ничего, что может вызвать исключение. `try` я убрал просто потому, что он здесь не нужен. Исправление Вашего кода состоит в другом - условии в `while`.